# Issue with jQuery waypoints after adding wrapping div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jQuery waypoints to change the color of certain elements when they meet the bounds defined. However, I have encountered an issue since adding a wrapper with css scroll snapping around all of the trigger elements.

Ever since adding the wrapper, the waypoint function won't fire. When there was no wrapper the waypoint function worked fine.

If anyone could help that would be great.

The simplified mark up is:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <nav>
    <svg class="logo"></svg>

    <a href="#">link</a>

    <button class="menu-button"></button>

  </nav>

  <section class="off-white">Content for section here</section>

  <section class="off-white">Content for section here</section>

  <section class="primary">Content for section here</section>

</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.wrapper { 
      scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; 
      overflow-y: scroll; 
      height: 100vh; 
     };

section, footer {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

the jQuery I am using is

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var primaryHeight = $(".primary").height()
    var offWhiteHeight = $(".off-white").height()
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      //scroll down code
      if(scroll > position) {
        $('.primary').waypoint(function() {
            $(".logo").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
            $(".nav-link").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
            $(".menu-button").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
          }, { offset: 0 });
          $('.off-white').waypoint(function() {
            $(".logo").css("color", "#3232FF")
            $(".nav-link").css("color", "#3232FF")
            $(".menu-button").css("color", "#3232FF")
          }, { offset: 0 });
          // scroll up code
      } else {
        $('.primary').waypoint(function() {
            $(".logo").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
            $(".nav-link").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
            $(".menu-button").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
          }, { offset: -primaryHeight+60 });
          $('.off-white').waypoint(function() {
            $(".logo").css("color", "#3232FF")
            $(".nav-link").css("color", "#3232FF")
            $(".menu-button").css("color", "#3232FF")
          }, { offset: -offWhiteHeight+60 });
      }
      position = scroll;
  });
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that! Ever since adding the wrapper, the waypoint function won't fire. When there was no wrapper the waypoint function worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might find this in future I have fixed this myself by doing the following:

before offset adding:

```
context: $(".wrapper")
```

and changing all instances of

```
$(window)
```

to

```
$(".wrapper")
```

see revised full jQuery code here:

```
var position = $(".wrapper").scrollTop();
  $(".wrapper").scroll(function() {
    var primaryHeight = $(".primary").height()
    var offWhiteHeight = $(".off-white").height()
      var scroll = $(".wrapper").scrollTop();
      //scroll down code
      if(scroll > position) {
        $('.primary').waypoint(function() {
            $(".logo").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
            $(".nav-link").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
            $(".menu-button").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
          }, {context: $(".wrapper"), offset: 60 });
          
          $('.off-white').waypoint(function() {
            $(".logo").css("color", "#3232FF")
            $(".nav-link").css("color", "#3232FF")
            $(".menu-button").css("color", "#3232FF")
          }, {context: $(".wrapper"), offset: 60 });
          // scroll up code
      } else {
        $('.primary').waypoint(function() {
            $(".logo").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
            $(".nav-link").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
            $(".menu-button").css("color", "#FFFFFF")
          }, {context: $(".wrapper"), offset: -primaryHeight+60 });
          $('.off-white').waypoint(function() {
            $(".logo").css("color", "#3232FF")
            $(".nav-link").css("color", "#3232FF")
            $(".menu-button").css("color", "#3232FF")
          }, {context: $(".wrapper"), offset: -offWhiteHeight+60 });
      }
      position = scroll;
  });
```